# Get Order from Invoice

Tags: magento-1.8, event-observer, invoice

I have an observer running on **`sales_order_invoice_save_after`**. I am able to retrieve the invoice from this observer however I am having some issues retrieving the order from the invoice. How can I retrieve an order from an invoice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Was easier than what I thought:

```
public function paymentSuccessful($observer)
{
    $invoice = $observer->getEvent()->getInvoice();
    $order = $invoice->getOrder();
    print_r($order->getData());
}
```